# Solving differential equation using a factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve $$(x^2-y)dx+xdy=0$$ Since in this form it is not an exact dif eq I multiply by a $\mu(x,y)$ factor so that it reduces to one. $$\mu (x^2-y)dx+\mu xdy=0$$ With the conditions $P_y' = Q_y'$ and $$P=\mu (x^2-y)$$ $$Q=\mu x$$ $$\mu _y'(x^2-y)-\mu=x\mu_x'+\mu$$ From here I don't know how to find $\mu$ since one is derivated with respect to $x$ and one to $y$. Could you help me? I took this easier example so that I can understand this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P=x^2-y\\Q=x\\\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=-1\\\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=1$$

Check if the operations beyond satisfy a Polynomial that either depends  only on x or y.

$$G(x)=\frac{\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}}{Q}\implies G(x)=-\frac2x$$

$$G(y)=\frac{\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}}{P}\implies G(y)=\frac{2}{x^2-y}$$
The Integrating factor:

$$\mu(x)=e^{-\int\frac2xdx}=x^{-2}$$
Now The ODE is  exact:
$$(1-x^{-2}y)dx+x^{-1}dy=0$$
Check:
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=-x^{-2}\\\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=-x^{-2}$$

You can solve it from here I guess.

Answer (score 0):

$$(x^2-y)dx+xdy=0$$
$$Pdx+Qdy=0$$
You can take an integrating factor that depends only on x
$$s=\partial_y P-\partial_x Q=-2$$
$$\int \frac {d \mu}{\mu}=\int \frac {\partial_y P-\partial_x Q} Q dx$$
$$\ln (\mu)=-2\int \frac {dx}x \implies \mu(x)=\frac 1 {x^2}$$
Then the equation becomes exact
$$(1-\frac y {x^2})dx+\frac 1xdy=0 \implies \partial_y P=\partial_x Q$$

Comment: Could you tell me how did you know to take on $x$ and not of $y$?

Comment: @Sonkun  well I guess I noted that Q depends only on $x$ and the difference between the partial derivative is a constant so I took $\mu=\mu(x)$

Comment: I see, so there is not like a general method? Because I want to understand how can I solve harder dif equations.

Comment: No general method that I know @Sonkun you can have integrating factor that depends on $x$ or on $y$ it depends on the equation..So I try this and that...Try to write the integrating factor that depends on y thats not possible and if it is possible its harder

Comment: @Sonkun I wrote my answer where you can see the "General Method" for Exact ODEs